# Android studio app crush after click on a button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-button

**When I press the edit button the program crashes and stops working.**

I need help with this is for a job for the university and I do not know where the fault is.

**The error is this: **

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: pjurado.com.a05reciclerviewobjeto, PID: 14577
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {pjurado.com.a05reciclerviewobjeto/pjurado.com.a05reciclerviewobjeto.AdapterDirectorio}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1932)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1615)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4472)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4430)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4791)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4759)
        at pjurado.com.a05reciclerviewobjeto.Editar.onClick(Editar.java:24)
```

Android_manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="pjurado.com.a05reciclerviewobjeto">
    
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".Editar" />
        </application>

</manifest>
```

AdapterDirectorio.java

```
package pjurado.com.a05reciclerviewobjeto;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AdapterDirectorio extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterDirectorio.MyViewHolder>  {

    private ArrayList<Contacto> directorio;
    public AdapterDirectorio(ArrayList directorio){
        this.directorio = directorio;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent,  false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.etNombre.setText(directorio.get(position).getNombre());
        holder.etTelefono.setText(directorio.get(position).getTelefono());
        holder.etEmail.setText(directorio.get(position).getEmail());
        holder.ivFoto.setImageResource(directorio.get(position).getFoto());
        holder.botonLlamar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String phoneNo = holder.etTelefono.getText().toString();
                String num = "tel:" + phoneNo;
                holder.context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(num)));
            }
        });
        holder.botonEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String[] email= {holder.etEmail.getText().toString()};
                Intent i= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                        .setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"))
                        .setType("text/plain")
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, email)
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hello")
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "HELLO WORLD");
                holder.context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Enviar email"));
            }
        });
        holder.botonEditar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(holder.context, Editar.class);
                holder.context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return directorio.size();
    }



    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public View mView;
        public TextView etNombre;
        public TextView etTelefono;
        public TextView etEmail;
        public ImageView ivFoto;
        public ImageButton botonLlamar;
        public ImageButton botonEmail;
        public ImageButton botonEditar;
        public Context context;



        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            etNombre = mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNombre);
            etTelefono = mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTelefono);
            etEmail = mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
            ivFoto = mView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            botonLlamar = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
            botonEmail = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
            botonEditar = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.botonEdicion);
            context = itemView.getContext();


        }
    }
}
```

Contacto.java

```
package pjurado.com.a05reciclerviewobjeto;

public class Contacto {
    private String Nombre;
    private String Telefono;
    private String email;
    private int foto;

    public int getFoto() {
        return foto;
    }

    public void setFoto(int foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    }

    public Contacto(String nombre, String telefono, String email, int foto) {
        Nombre = nombre;
        Telefono = telefono;
        this.email = email;
        this.foto = foto;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        Nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getTelefono() {
        return Telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        Telefono = telefono;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Editar.java

````
package pjurado.com.a05reciclerviewobjeto;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Editar extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.modificacion);

    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Editar.this, AdapterDirectorio.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```
```
mainActivity.java
package pjurado.com.a05reciclerviewobjeto;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<Contacto> directorio = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
    private AdapterDirectorio myAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        creaDatos();

        myRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        myAdapter = new AdapterDirectorio(directorio);

        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        


    }

    private void creaDatos(){
        directorio.add(new Contacto("Pedro Jurado", "987123456", "pjurado@gmail.com", R.drawable.foto));
        directorio.add(new Contacto("Pepe Pérez", "987121256", "ppe@gmail.com", R.drawable.foto));
        directorio.add(new Contacto("Antonio Gómex", "934643456", "aoox@gmail.com", R.drawable.foto));
        directorio.add(new Contacto("Antonio Gómex", "934643456", "aoox@gmail.com", R.drawable.foto));
        directorio.add(new Contacto("Antonio Gómex", "934643456", "aoox@gmail.com", R.drawable.foto));
        directorio.add(new Contacto("Antonio Gómex", "934643456", "aoox@gmail.com", R.drawable.foto));
        directorio.add(new Contacto("Antonio Gómex", "934643456", "aoox@gmail.com", R.drawable.foto));
        directorio.add(new Contacto("Antonio Gómex", "934643456", "aoox@gmail.com", R.drawable.foto));
        directorio.add(new Contacto("Antonio Gómex", "934643456", "aoox@gmail.com", R.drawable.foto));
        directorio.add(new Contacto("Antonio Gómex", "934643456", "aoox@gmail.com", R.drawable.foto));
    }
}
````

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

item_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewNombre"
                android:layout_width="497dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTelefono"
                    android:layout_width="164dp"
                    android:layout_height="51dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton5"
                    card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/boton_redondo"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton4"
                    card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    card_view:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/boton_redondo"
                    android:contentDescription="TODO"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/botonEdicion"
                    card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    card_view:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/botonEdicion"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/boton_redondo"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    card_view:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="395dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewEmail"
                android:layout_width="494dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

modificacion.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Nombre y apellidos"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.079"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.079"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Telefono"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.079"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="Modificación de datos"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.098"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAceptacion"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Confrimar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

boton_redondo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"></solid>
    <size android:height="50dp" android:width="50dp"></size>

</shape>
```

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Editar.this, AdapterDirectorio.class);
        startActivity(intent); You are calling an Adapter class here that is the issue.

Comment: To expand on @ShamirKp comment, you can only use `startActivity()` to start another activity declared in the `Android_manifest`, that's why you can see the error `Unable to find explicit activity class {[...].AdapterDirectorio}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`. Which activity are you intent to start, as you only have two in your Manifest: `MainActivity` and `Editar`?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling an Adapter inside the intent where you should call an activity. You set the adapter correctly in the MainActivity.java. Consider which class you need to call for the Editar.java and replace the AdapterDirectorio.class with that specific activity i.e ModificationActivity.java

```
public void onClick(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Editar.this, ModificationActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```